# Create an break before element

Tags: html, css

I trying to add an break before an element in css without changing the underneath html codes. I been searching around this forum for answers, but couldn't make it work across the different browsers.

HTML ( unchangeable, as it's part of an `joomla` component )

```
    <span id="mod_login_usernametext-map"> <label for="mod_login_username-map"> Email </label> </span>

    <span><input type="text" name="username" id="mod_login_username-map" class="inputbox-map" /></span>

    <-- here i want the break -->

    <span id="mod_login_passwordtext-map"><label for="mod_login_password-map">Password</label></span>&nbsp;<span><input type="password" name="passwd" id="mod_login_password-map" class="inputbox-map" />

    <-- and break here -->
    <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="mod_login_remember-map" class="inputbox-map" value="yes" /> <span id="mod_login_remembermetext-map"><label for="mod_login_remember-map">Remember me</label></span>
```

I tried `#mod_login_passwordtext-map:before { content: '\A';white-space: pre-line; }` but didn't turn out very well in `firefox`, `chrome` fine..

Using `display: break` doesn't put the input box on the same level.. Easiest would have been if I just could have added an wrap element around, but no can do that..

Any tips?

Comment: It's hard to say anything without you posting some css code, but first of all try with `margin` and `display: block` or `display: inline-block` properties.

Comment: I added some css above.. tried this #mod_login_passwordtext-map {display: block;}
#mod_login_username-map { display: inline-block; } , but it doesn't work as they are not adjacent or something

Comment: You'd post a link to the website we're talking about and maybe then I could think of some solution.

Comment: http://www.esge.org/login , want the 'remember me' also to start on new line. Raisch answers works very well for the first two lines(login/pass), but doesn't really apply for input boxes

Comment: @user1693820 - Look at the edit of my answer. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with this css:

```
#mod_login_passwordtext-map:before {
  content: '\A';
  white-space: pre;
}
```

Demo: [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hyEAC)

Works well on FF and Chrome for me.

Best regards

**EDIT:**

This will add a break to your login button too + align the two `input` fields:

```
#mod_loginform-map #mod_login_passwordtext-map:before,
#mod_loginform-map .cbLoginButtonSpan:before {
  content: '\A';
  white-space: pre;
}

#mod_login_usernametext-map label,
#mod_login_passwordtext-map label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 6em;
}
```

Demo: [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Geapw)

**EDIT 2:**

U cant add `:before` and `:after` pseudo classes to `input` elements.

Why?

Because `:before` is added before **the content** of an element and `:after` is added after **the conetent** of an element **not** before or after the element itself.

An input element dont have content, only a value.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT 3:**

To get a new line, with CSS, for the *Remember me* `input` i see only one way.

```
#mod_loginform-map #mod_login_passwordtext-map:before,
#mod_loginform-map .cbLoginButtonSpan:before,
#mod_loginform-map span:nth-child(4):after {
  content: '\A';
  white-space: pre;
}
```

Demo: [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wylEm)

But this workaround is a bit crappy in my eyes.

Best regards

Comment: thanks alot, that worked.. guess shouln't had used white-space: pre-line; .. One last thing, I'm trying to apply this to an input element, but then that's not working.. That code doesn't apply for inputs elements? #mod_login_remember-map:before {content: '\A';white-space: pre;}

Comment: @user1693820 - U cant add `:before` and `:after` pseudo classes to input elements. Because `:before` is added before the content of an element and `:after` is added after the conetent of an element **not** before or after the element itself, and an input element dont have content only an value. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the help.. So there's no way of getting the input of 'remember me' down to a new line? Now it's on the same line as the password field. It's hard to catch the last span of the line before as i doesn't have any classes assigned to it..

Comment: @user1693820 - Look at my **EDIT 3**! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Why not just set `#mod_login_passwordtext-map` to `display:block`? Or even do some float/clearing on your markup.

http://jsfiddle.net/TUGCX/1/

```
#mod_login_passwordtext-map {
    clear:both;
}

span {
    float:left;
}

/* You don't need that. */
input {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:5px;
}
```

​
**Note:** `display: break` is not valid css!